# Cache loaded models in OpenCV DNN module

Tags: python, opencv

In OpenCV, I load the Caffe network model:

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("proto_file", "model_file")
```

Further down in my code, I feed the model with image(s):

```
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image)
net.setInput(blob)
```

This works just fine. However, I would like to cache loaded network from step 1 and avoid loading the files from disk for every single request to my application. Ideally I would have something like this:

```
import cv2

net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("proto_file", "model_file")

def awesomeFn(image):
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image)
    net.setInput(blob)
```

That way, I can call my `awesomeFn` as many times as I like without loading the network from disk. On my machine, step 1 (loading model files from disk) takes anywhere between 6ms and 12ms.

The problem I see is with `net.setInput(blob)` as we already have a cached and globally declared network that we feed with data. If my application processes user files at say 100 req/sec speed, chances are that some users would be getting other user's data in the response.

Is there any way to cache the network from step 1 and only feed it with fresh data every time the request arrives? I would like to avoid loading the model from disk for every request at all costs.

Comment: Will the apllication be deployed to web? If so, I would try to find another to make sure every user gets the right response. If it's running locally and you just mean, different functions accesing it, it will be computed in the right order anyway...

Comment: Yes, it will be deployed to Web hence my worries described in the question above

Comment: I think thats a question of your (REST) API design then.

Comment: Not really, no. It's a question about re-using already loaded DNN without having to load the files from disk for every subsequent request. API/REST design here is irrelevant.

Comment: well i thought you fear that, if one user submits a request 10ms after another one, but he receives his response faster, he gets a wrong classification. that is from my point of view prevented with correct queuing?